# connection string project setting in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

how to set the connection strings(by going Project->ProjectProperties->Setting) in visual studio 2005 of mdf database file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to find connection string for any databse

http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: and rest of the process in defined in below post
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wabtadw6.aspx